# Using wget 1.12 centos 6 to batch download and rename output files

Tags: input, wget

using file wget

```
wget -c --load-cookies cookies.txt http://www.example.com/file
```

works fine

```
wget -c --load-cookies cookies.txt http://www.example.com/file.mpg -O filename_to_save_as.mpg
```

when I use

```
wget -c --load-cookies cookies.txt -i /dir/inputfile.txt
```

to pass urls from a text file it wget it works as expected.  Is there any way to pass a url from a text file and still rename the out put file as in example 2 above. I have tried passing the -O option with an argument but wget tell me "invalid URL http://site.com/file.mpg -O new_name.mpg: scheme missing"

also I have tried escaping after the url, quotes and formatting in such a way as

```
url = "http://foo.bar/file.mpg" -O new_name.mpg
```

is there any way to use an input file and still change the output file name using wget?

if not would a shell script be more appropriate? If so how should it be written?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that `wget` supports it, but it's possible to do with a small shell script.
First, create an input file like this (`inputfile.txt`):

```
http://www.example.com/file1.mpg    filename_to_save_as1.mpg
http://www.example.com/file2.mpg    filename_to_save_as2.mpg
http://www.example.com/file3.mpg    filename_to_save_as3.mpg
```

The url and the filename are separated by a `tab` character.
Then use this bash script (`wget2.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
    URL=$(echo "$line" | cut -f 1 )
    FILENAME=$(echo "$line" | cut -f 2 )
    echo wget -c --load-cookies cookies.txt "$URL" -O "$FILENAME"
done
```

with this command:

```
echo input.txt | wget2.sh
```

A more simple solution is to write a shell script which contains the `wget` command for every file:

```
#!/bin/bash
wget -c --load-cookies cookies.txt http://www.example.com/file.mpg1 -O filename_to_save_as1.mpg
wget -c --load-cookies cookies.txt http://www.example.com/file.mpg2 -O filename_to_save_as2.mpg
wget -c --load-cookies cookies.txt http://www.example.com/file.mpg3 -O filename_to_save_as3.mpg
```